# Are WM_ERASEBKGND messages posted to the message queue?

Tags: c, winapi

`WM_PAINT` messages are not posted to the message queue, but rather when the message queue is empty, the `WM_PAINT` message is sent to the window procedure (if some area of the window is invalid).

However, are `WM_ERASEBKGND` messages sent in some similar way, or are they simply posted to the message queue (the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648055%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) don't say anything about this).

Comment: That's not quite how WM_PAINT works. They aren't sent when the queue is empty. When the queue is empty, `GetMessage` synthesises them.

Comment: @David Heffernan I don't mean *"sent"* as in it is sent to the message queue, I said *"sent to the window procedure"*, which means that the window procedure is called (by `DispatchMessage()` I suppose) and passed `WM_PAINT` as argument. Am I right?

Comment: Well, that's also how queued messages end up in the window procedure. But many messages land in the window procedure without passing through the message loop and its call to `DispatchMessage`. `WM_PAINT` is different, it does pass through the message loop, but is not actually posted to the message queue.

Comment: @David Heffernan Yes you are right, this is my understanding. So `GetMessage()` is the one that retrieves messages from the message queue, and if it sees that the message queue is empty and there is some area of the window that is invalid, it fills the `MSG` structure with a `WM_PAINT` message, and then `DispatchMessage()` calls the window procedure as usual, correct?

Comment: Why do people keep asking these sorts of questions? Why does it matter so much?

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Why? Curisosity of how things work?

Comment: `WM_PAINT` messages generated by `UpdateWindow()` and `RedrawWindow()` are delivered directly to the window procedure without going through the message loop at all.

Answer (score 4):

It is both, not untypical for Windows messages.  It will be sent when the program executes a command like UpdateWindow() or processes a message like WM_SYSCOMMAND that moves or resizes the window.  It will be posted when the program has called InvalidateRect().

Same is true for WM_PAINT, normally a "posted" message but only returned by GetMessage() when the message queue is empty.  It however will be sent when you call UpdateWindow(), ensuring the window is painted when it returns.

Not taking a dependency on those implementation details is pretty important.

Comment: *"Not taking a dependency on those implementation details is pretty important"* You mean I should assume that in a (near) future Windows version `UpdateWindow()` could not call the window procedure directly, or that `InvalidateRect()` could call the window procedure directly instead of waiting until the code execution returns to the message loop?

Comment: I mean that you don't have a time machine that can go back to know how the message got generated.  You just don't know, it wasn't necessarily done by code in your process or source code.

Comment: Oh okay! what I'm interested in is what will happen when I does something like `UpdateWindow()` and not to know how the received messages got generated.

Comment: You said about `WM_ERASEBKGND`: *"It will be posted when the program has called InvalidateRect()"*, does that mean it will posted to the message queue just like most other messages (and not like `WM_PAINT`)?

Comment: I don't know.  Pretty high odds that it is synthesized like WM_PAINT.